# The type or namespace name 'UniRx' could not be found on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, unirx

I pretty much looked everywhere... but couldn't find anything that could debug my problem.

The only thing I do in a script is "using UniRx" to have the following error : The type or namespace name 'UniRx' could not be found.

What i tried:

- On Unity, downloading from Package Manager with "Add Package with git URL"
- On Unity, downloading from Package Manager with the normal way: Download -> import (into folder Plugins)

On each part, i also tried:

- "Reimport All"
- Closing and opening back Unity Hub then Unity

I found nothing much on google except for having this problem only on Visual Studio (which is not my actually problem since Unity itself doesn't accept UniRx)
But those who have that problem, i read that you need to "Assets" -> "Open C# Project"

Can anyone help me with my problem on Unity ? Searched for hours but still stuck :(

Unity Version: 2021.3.3f1

Comment: Do you have assemblies in your project? This would require to add UniRx asm to the one in which the code is stored.

Comment: On a side note, UniRx is no longer properly maintained so it is risky to use it and there have been reports of clashes with newer Unity versions. Also, UniRx is slow and memory consuming while Observable pattern can now be achieved with latest .NET (the new inclusion of it in Unity is the reason for the clashes).

Comment: I know people who are using it and have the latest version of Unity. These people say that they don't have any problem.

Comment: They may have fixed the Observable clash with (issue 510). 181 open issues tells me to be careful though https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx/issues

Answer (score 0):

Well seems like my problem was like fafase said... I totally forgot about assemblies since i don't use Unity much and since it's been a long time i didn't continue my project.